# Alert message to remote SQL DB form local SQL DB if no data from software application

Tags: sql-server, alerts

I am looking for a solution for my software application which has local SQL DB for data storage and from the local SQL DB replicate the data in real time to a remote SQL DB for visualizing the data in dashboard. This is possible with SQL configuration.

But I need to have another feature, which is kind of a job scheduler - if the local DB is not getting the data from the application for 15 minutes, I need to send a binary alert or add a field to the schema to notify the customer that there is no data coming in.

I cannot send an email because the database server is in a network isolated from the enterprise network.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you running on the local and remote SQL Server instances?

Comment: Is your question how to determine when data is not being replicated. how to send a binary alert (whatever that is), or both? To avoid downvotes, you need to ask question rather than stating requirements and show what you've tried.

Comment: on the local DB  the data will come in real time as normal operation.. if there is a image processing result from my software.. let say there is no data coming in form application to local db for 15 minutes i need to send a alert message to remote db that  there is no data..  who can i do this .???sorry actually i explained what is my problem and asked the questions really sorry if did not make it very clear as i am new to DB;s.

Comment: Hi handyD,  local DB is SQL standard 2016  and remote DB is also SQL 2014 standard